# Delete entire row if Consequent Data is Matching in Excel 2007

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem is if my columns Consequent Data is Matching then it should Delete row.

for e.g.
**Before**
column A   column B

aaa          10

aaa          10

aaa          5

bbb          6

aaa          10

bbb          5

**After**
column A   column B

aaa          10

aaa          5

bbb          6

bbb          5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select all the data in column a and b and then on the data ribbon select remove duplicates.

Comment: have you selected both of the coulmns?I tried this again and it worked.